# JSON is not serializable - json.dump doesnt recognize list correctly

Tags: json, list, python-2.7, serializable

I am trying to create a json dump from a given list of dicts.
the values are in the below format

> [{'id1':1, 'id2':2, 'distance':23} , {'id1':1, 'id2':2, 'distance':23}]

When I run the code (pasted below), it gives me a JSON not serializable TypeError. The problem is that even though the variable 'distance_list' was initialized as a list (**using distance_list = list()**), the function **isinstanceof(distance_list, list)**  returns false showing that python doesn't recognize the variable as a list object.

But print(distance_list) shows 'list'. 
I am confused. My question is, how can print show a 'list' type and isinstanceof() not identify it as a 'list'?. and because python doesn't identify it as list, json.dump fails.

calling function()

```
def create_habitat_pairs_and_save(pdata_unsorted, field_radius, outputfile):

ulog.logit(2, "Entering function create_habitat_pairs_and_save... ")
distance_list = list()
rowCounter = 0
irowcount = 0
loop_counter = 0
sort_colname_coordinates = ['mapX', 'mapY']  # sort columns for pandas dataframe

rowcount = len(pdata_unsorted.index)
pdata = sortdata(pdata_unsorted, sort_colname_coordinates)  # sort input file contents by X and Y coordinates    

for index_i, row_i in pdata.iterrows():
    loop_counter += 1
    utilities.show_progress(loop_counter, rowcount)  #show progress on screen
    irowcount+=1
    pointer = irowcount
    x1 = int(row_i['mapX'])
    y1 = int(row_i['mapY'])
    rowCounter = 0
    yrange_trigger = False

    for index_j, row_j in pdata[pointer: rowcount].iterrows():
        x2 = int(row_j['mapX'])
        y2 = int(row_j['mapY'])
        rowCounter += 1
        if x2 <= x1 + field_radius:
            if y2 < y1 - field_radius:
                continue
            else:
                if y2 >= y1 - field_radius and y2 <= y1 + field_radius:
                    yrange_trigger = True
                    distance = compute_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                    if distance <= field_radius and distance != 0:
                        entry = {'id1':row_i['id'], 'id2': row_j['id'], 'distance': distance}
                        distance_list.append(entry)
                else:
                    break
        else:
            break
writefile(distance_list, outputfile)  # write the habitat pairs into json file for future use
```

file to write to json (called from the function above)

```
def writefile(distance_list, filename):
ulog.logit(2, "writefile... ")
with open(filename, mode = 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(distance_list, f)
f.close()
```